# AWS: two instances: On one ec2 instance, curl the webservices running using nginx doocker image on another ec2 instance: get Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, curl, amazon-ec2

As the title discussed, how do I set Netwrok ACL on both ec2 instances to allow curl from one instance to another?

Comment: In general, you should never change the Network ACLs in an AWS VPC.  Leave the network ACLs with their default "Allow All" setting. Instead, use **Security Groups** to control what traffic can go in/out of resources. What is the configuration of the Security Groups associated with your two Amazon EC2 instances?

Comment: This an assignment from the course, it requires me to change Network ACL for the action, and the security group allows everything in and out on both

Comment: Since your problem is that the instances cannot communicate, then you should at least start by keeping the Network ACLs with their default "Allow All" settings. If the Security Group also "allows everything in and out" then something else is the problem. (That is, not networking.) Try to get them connecting first, before you restrict traffic via networking controls.

Comment: Good to know that you figured it out! If you think your solution would help future readers, please add an Answer (yes, you can answer your own Question). However, if you don't think it will help future readers, feel free to delete the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, the user data did not work for some reason when I creating the VM2 which would hosting Nginx servers. I manually installed the Nginx and ran it. For NACL:
**VM 1:**
**Inbound/Outbound Customs TCP 1024-65535 IP of VM 2 Allow**

**VM 2**
**Inbound Custom TCP port of Nignx services IP of VM 1 Allow**
**Outbound Custom TCP 1024-65535 IP of VM 1 Allow**

I hope this help.